# DateTime.Ticks in .NET - how and why is it used?

Tags: .net

I have been using C# for quite some time, and have suddenly come across `DateTime.Now.Ticks`.

What is it for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It represents the total number of ticks in *local* time (not UTC) since the DateTime epoch, which is midnight on January 1st in the year 1AD. (Each tick is 100 nanoseconds; there are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.)

To break it down, [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now) is a *static property* returning a [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) representing the current time.

Then [`DateTime.Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks) is an *instance* property on DateTime, returning the number of ticks since midnight on January 1st, 1AD. It gets more complicated due to time zones (and [DateTime's poor design](https://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html)) but that's the basics.

A tick is the smallest unit of time used in `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`. You typically use it to make sure you can completely round-trip a value without losing any information.

Note that it's *not* the same thing as the ticks returned by [`Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks), which are system-dependent; their length can be determined using [`StopWatch.Frequency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency).

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing it's the safest way to communicate time between disparate systems between potentially different technology stacks.

a common guaranteed way to communicate time without worrying about structure, format and definitions of date time strings, leaving it up to the implementing developer to read and interpret